# Single sessions in LogicalDOC BE

Tags: php, soap, session-management, dms

For a project that I am recently assigned to, we used to work with the free LogicalDOC Community Edition. We are considering buying the business edition, however, in this edition you only get a limited number of consecutive sessions.

The project consists of a non-framework PHP application, which currently spawns a SOAP session to LogicalDOC for every page request but doesn't logout in the end. Since there is currently only one consecutive session possible, the system blocks after one page request. In the code, there is no single communication layer, DAO or connection pool. However, there is a LogicalDOC class which does the initial authentication and saves the `session_id` as a global variable.

My current suggestion to the company is to rewrite the system with a framework, with session pooling and smart objects. However, did anybody encounter a comparable problem and was able to solve this in a less time consuming way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API documentation and sample resources are published here: https://www.logicaldoc.com/support/api

As you may note, you can open a session invoking the method Auth.login
The method returns a SID that identifies your session.
You can then use this token in subsequent invocations to re-use the same session. 
There is no need to adopt a framework you can just save this SID in a plain file.
At the end your work, just close the session with Auth.logout